# Does $x$-component $\hat{L}_x$ of angular momentum commute with $\hat{x}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, commutator

Question from lecture notes:

> What of the following operators does not commute with $\hat x$?
>
> A. $ \hat L_x  $
>
> B. $ \hat L_y  $
>
> C. $ \hat L_z  $
>
> D. None of the above.

The answer is A. But when I compute this myself, the answer is $0$, indicating they do commute, yes?
Here is my work:
$$[\hat x, \hat L_x]$$
$$=-i\hbar x(y\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} - z\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}) + i\hbar(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial x}{\partial y})f + i\hbar x(y\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} - z\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}) $$
The first and the third term cancel, the derivatives in the middle term all evaluate to $0$ which kills the entire term as well, resulting in $0$ total. Am I right, or is my professor? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. $L_x$ commutes with x as it does not contain $\partial_x$.